# Logic checking statements

Tags: python

I need to add 2 logic statements in the following code.  I need one for if you are under the age of 18 and another one that only lets you enter 2 letters for a state.  Both statements need to exit the program and I think that is where I am confused at.  I am very new to python, so any help is greatly appreciated.  I think I can put if statements but I don't know how to make them exit the program, I only know how to make them print

```
print('Welcome to the US Voter Registration System')
con = input('Do You Want to Continue: Yes Or No? ')
while con == 'Yes':
    name = input('Please Enter Your First Name: ')
    name2 = input('Please Enter Your Last Name: ')

    age = int(input('Please Enter Your Age *** YOU MUST BE 18 OR OLDER ***: '))

    cit = input('Are You A US Citizen? Answer Yes or No: ')

    state = input('Please Enter Your State?' 'Please only 2 letters: ')

    zipc = int(input('Please Enter Your Zip Code? '))

    con = input('You Are Finished Please Type Done: ')

    print('NAME: ', name, name2)
    print('AGE: ', age)
    print('US CITIZEN:', cit)
    print('STATE: ', state)
    print('ZIP CODE: ', zipc)
    print('Thank You For Using the US Voter Registration System ')
    print('Please Check Your Mail For More Voting Information ')
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `sys.exit()` (don't forget `import sys` in the top of your program). Although I suggest you read the Python Tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ before delving into any serious code projects.

Comment: You can use try and except ref: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()` to exit a program (remember to `import sys` at the top of your file).

You can check if age is below 18 with `if age < 18:` ("if age is less than 18"). For length of the state value you can use the `len` function which gives you the length of the string in characters (technically it gives you the length of a sequence or anything implementing the `__len__` method, but that's not important with what you're trying to do).

You can also use `break` to end the `while` loop instead of exiting the program.

So to implement those measures:

```
import sys

print('Welcome to the US Voter Registration System')

...

    age = int(input('Please Enter Your Age *** YOU MUST BE 18 OR OLDER ***: '))

    if age < 18:
        print("Must be over 18!")
        sys.exit()  # or break to end the loop

    ..

    state = input('Please Enter Your State?' 'Please only 2 letters: ')
   
    if len(state) != 2:
        print("State must be exactly two letters.")
        sys.exit()  # or break to end the loop

    ..
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes sense....like alot of sense.